# URL to open details in summary inside a javascript tab content menu

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, tabs

I would like to have a unique URL to open content inside a summary tag, that's nested inside a JavaScript tab menu.

Here is the tab HTML menu :

```
<div class="tab">
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openMediatype(event, 'current')">currently reading</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openMediatype(event, 'recent')">recently read</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openMediatype(event, 'webarticles')">web articles</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openMediatype(event, 'pdfs')">pdfs</button>
</div>
```

Here is the JavaScript code for the tab:

```
<script>
    function openMediatype(evt, mediaType) {
        var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
        tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
        for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
            tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
        for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
            tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
        }
        document.getElementById(mediaType).style.display = "block";
        evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
    }
</script>
```

Here is the summary/detail content :

```
<div id="webarticles" class="tabcontent">
<a href="#webarticles"> <h3>articles from around the web</h3> </a> 

<details> THIS IS THE DETAIL EXPANDED CONTENT THAT I WOULD LIKE TO HAVE OPENED UPON URL LINK :)
<summary style="background-color:#c9e8cf;"> <i> Publication </i>, "Article Title" Date </summary> <br><br>

<a href="https://ewyorktim.com/article"> Read the article </a><br>
<h2>&#9825; Posted : Monday 18 September 2023</h2><br>

<p> paragraphy paragraphy para para para paragraphy

</p> </details>
```

I tried this (and a few other scripts that didn't work).

The following code sort of worked, but it would directly open the tab upon opening the web page, all the time, and not just with a specific url like:  https://www.website.com/TabPage#TabIWantOpen

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>

<script>
var a = 4
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".tabcontent a").click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $(".panel").hide();
    $(".tabcontent a.active").removeClass("active");
    $this.addClass("active").blur();
    var panel = $this.attr("href");
    $(panel).fadeIn(250);
    return false;
  });
$(".tabcontent a[href='#webarticles']").click();
});
</script>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.